# Can REST or the ArcGIS API for Flex read VAT tables from a Raster?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, lidar

When publishing a bare earth DEM that has a VAT table, or value attribute table *"A VAT is a table containing attributes for a grid, including user-defined attributes, the values assigned to cells in the grid, and a count of the cells with those values"*

...The fields are empty in the REST service where there should be values.  Anyone know how to consume the VAT table that resides inside the gdb.?

I want to be able to use the identify tool to depict elevation values.

Comment: Have you considered using the [Elevations SOE](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/arcobjects-net-api/details?entryID=87BEC705-1422-2418-34B5-308930DE323A)?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to use the identify tool to depict elevation values.

If Kirk's solution doesn't help, a workaround is to convert the grid to a polygon, and run the Identify task on the polygon layer.

The polygons wouldn't be displayed on the map, but would simply be used when clicking on the map.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about rasters in gdb's, but for GRID's you can use code to add the VAT to the map as a standalone table.  Presumably you could then publish it as a mapservice and consume it via the REST api.  Seems like there might be a similar back door for VAT's in gdb.

```
private void Test()
{
    var ws = OpenWS("esriDataSourcesFile.ArcInfoWorkspaceFactory", @"C:\projects\forums");

    var table = ((IFeatureWorkspace)ws).OpenTable("states1.VAT");

    var saTable = new StandaloneTableClass() as IStandaloneTable;
    saTable.Name = ((IDataset)table).Name;
    saTable.Table = table;
    ((IStandaloneTableCollection)ArcMap.Document.FocusMap).AddStandaloneTable(saTable);
}

private IWorkspace OpenWS(string progID, string path)
{
    var t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progID);
    var wsf = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IWorkspaceFactory;
    return wsf.OpenFromFile(path, 0);
}
```

[image]